# Perform additional logic in model with async retrofit call

Tags: java, android, http, retrofit, retrofit2

My goal is to perform some additional logic based on a Retrofit call's result in the model, before having the callback be called on the UI thread.

I am purposefully using retrofit since I've read it is more performant than AsyncTask. I am implementing an MVP design pattern.

The following is what I am trying to achieve, with some code snippets of what I already have, with some of the comments addressing what I want to be able to do. 
Presenter:

```
public class Presenter {

    private IView view;
    private IModel model;

    public void onGetPrice(ExchangeType exchangeType) {
        Call<Double> call = model.getPrice(exchangeType);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Double>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Double> call, Response<Double> response) {
                // Assuming success
                this.view.updatePrice(response.body())
            }

            ...
        });
    }
}
```

Implementation of model:

```
public class Model implements IModel {

    private HashMap<ExchangeType, BaseExchange> exchangeMap; //Initialized elsewhere
    @Override
    public Call<double> getPrice(ExchangeType exchangeType) {
        return exchangeMap.get(exchangeType).getPrice();
    }
}
```

An implementation of BaseExchange:

```
public abstract BaseExchange {

    public abstract Call<Double> getPrice();
}

public interface IExchange1Api {

    @GET("some_uri")
    public Call<Exchange1ObjectA> getObjectA();
}

public class Exchange1ObjectA {

    public double Price;
    ...
}

public class Exchange1 {

    private IExchange1Api apiClient; // Initialized elsewhere using retrofit.

    @Override
    public Call<Double> getPrice() {
        Call<Exchange1ObjectA> call = apiClient.getObjectA();
        // How to convert Call<Exchange1ObjectA> to Call<Double>? The double 
        // value that needs to be returned is based on Exchange1ObjectA.Price, 
        // though needs some additional logic done. 
    }
}
```

The reason for the need of a BaseExchange object instead of using the retrofit generated client directly in the presenter is that I also have a different implementation of BaseExchange.

```
public interface IExchange2Api {

    @GET("another_uri_zzz")
    public Call<Exchange2ObjectZZZ> getObjectZZZ();
}

public class Exchange2ObjectZZZ {

    public double Price;
    ... // Properties that are very different from Exchange1ObjectA, 
    // since this and Exchange1ObjectA represent fundamentaly different concepts.
}

public class Exchange2 {

    private IExchange2Api apiClient; // Initialized elsewhere using retrofit.

    @Override
    public Call<Double> getPrice() {
        Call<Exchange2ObjectZZZ> call = apiClient.getObjectZZZ();
        // How to convert Call<Exchange1ObjectZZZ> to Call<Double>? The double 
        // value that needs to be returned is based on Exchange1ObjectZZZ.Price, 
        // though needs some additional logic done.  
    }
}
```

Essentially, the way to get the price on each exchange differs fundamentally, and the response objects returned by each exchange's API cannot be standardized through a base class. Exchange2ObjectZZZ represents a different business logic concept from Exchange1ObjectA; it just happens to be that the two contain the price that is desired. Furthermore, Exchange2ObjectZZZ may be used in  a very different manner in another call to the exchange which does not involve the price at all.

I am stuck on how to solve this issue without duplicating a lot of code in the presenter or creating a lot of anemic interfaces/DTOs. An alternative approach to this entirely that I can see is if I pass in a lambda to the model's getPrice() method, which gets passed in to the exchange's getPrice() method, which is then called in a callback declared on the individual exchange object. However, that seems like code which is very hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Call` make retrofit interface return `Single`, than you'll be able to convert the response to any object using `flatMap()` operator.

```
public interface IExchange2Api {
    @GET("another_uri_zzz")
    public Single<Exchange2ObjectZZZ> getObjectZZZ();
}
```

Now in the client code:

```
api.getObjectZZZ()
   .flatMap(new Function<Exchange2ObjectZZZ, SingleSource<AnotherObject>>() {
        @Override
        public SingleSource<AnotherObject> apply(Exchange2ObjectZZZ objectZZZ) throws Exception {
            AnotherObject anotherObject = objectZZZ.toAnotherObject();
            return Single.just(anotherObject);
        }
    })
```

In order for Retrofit to be able to return `Single` you have to add call adapter factory when building retrofit instance:

```
Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(...)
    .client(...)
    .addConverterFactory(...)
    .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

Comment: Interesting. I've never used rxjava before. I'll give it a shot hopefully tomorrow. I'm guessing after I get the converted Single object back, I call the .subscribe method on it in the Presenter to update the UI? Do I need to manually specify the UI thread, or will rxjava default to the UI thread like retrofit's callback?

Comment: You have to specify, that you want operation to take place on a background thread and the result to be fetched on main thread: `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())`.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit is a networking library while Asynctask provides an easy way to offload tasks to another thread. They aren't exactly interchangeable unless you use Asynctask to roll your own networking solution. So, go ahead and use the threading solution you prefer.

On a side note, if you use your own Converter, you can do additional computation off the main thread before returning the results.